# W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have made a basic shopping list app that utilises a recyclerview to display the list items. I am trying to add a settings screen using navigation with fragments. I am running into the issue where my recyclerview & data display when I open the app, however when I go to the settings menu then back to the main screen there's no recyclerview. Logcat shows the error "W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.shoppinglist

import android.app.Dialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RVAdapter.ListItemClickInterface {
lateinit var itemsRV: RecyclerView
lateinit var addFAB: FloatingActionButton
lateinit var list: List<ListItems>
lateinit var RVAdapter: RVAdapter
lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.fragment_main))
    itemsRV = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    addFAB = findViewById(R.id.idFABAdd)
    list = ArrayList<ListItems>()
    RVAdapter = RVAdapter(list, this)
    itemsRV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    itemsRV.adapter = RVAdapter
    val repository = Repository(Database(this))
    val factory = ViewModelFactory(repository)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(ViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.getAllListItems().observe(this, Observer {
        RVAdapter.list = it
        RVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })

    addFAB.setOnClickListener {
        openDialog()
    }

}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment_main)
    return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

fun openDialog() {
    val dialog = Dialog(this)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_dialog)
    val cancelButton = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnCancel)
    val addButton = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnAdd)
    val itemEdt = dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.idEditItemName)
    val itemQuantityEdt = dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.idEditItemQuantity)

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
    addButton.setOnClickListener {
        val itemName: String = itemEdt.text.toString()
        val itemQuantity: String = itemQuantityEdt.text.toString()
        if (itemName.isNotBlank() && itemQuantity.isNotBlank()) {
            val items = ListItems(itemName, itemQuantity)
            viewModel.insert(items)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Item Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            RVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            dialog.dismiss()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Enter All Info To Add Item", 

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        }
        dialog.show()
    }

    override fun onItemClick(listItems: ListItems) {
        viewModel.delete(listItems)
        RVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
package com.example.shoppinglist

import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*

class HomeFragment : Fragment()  {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        idFABSettings.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_settingsFragment)
        }

        loadSettings()
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private fun loadSettings(){
        val sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

        val theme = sp.getBoolean("theme_switch",false)

    }

}
```

SettingsFragment.kt

```
package com.example.shoppinglist

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_rv_item"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/idFABAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorSecondary"
        android:contentDescription="Add Item Button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:tint="@android:color/white" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/idFABSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorSecondary"
        android:contentDescription="Add Item Button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:tint="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.shoppinglist.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="Settings" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.shoppinglist.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Shopping List"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/settingsFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Not sure if any more info is required. Apologies in advance - I am new to android studio & kotlin.

Comment: `lateinit` has nothing to do with it because that adapter is initialized in `onCreate()`. @Tokorae, where are you hosting these fragments? If you host your fragments in MainActivity, it's weird that you have a RecyclerView in your MainActivity. How is there room to show all the fragments you're navigating between if there's a RecyclerView on the screen, too?

Comment: Typically, if you are using Fragments, the code in the hosting Activity will be minimal. There might be a layout that shows a couple of small persistent things like a shared action bar and maybe a side drawer menu, along with a fragment container that takes up most of the screen. But it's up to the Fragments to show the main content of the app.

Comment: The fragment in activity_main.xml, that contains the androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment, is that what you’re referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to work with views that are specific to HomeFragment's layout through the MainActivity. This will not work correctly. The first time you start the activity, in `onCreate` you use `findViewById` to find the view with ID `recyclerView`, and it successfully finds it because at that time the view is part of the HomeFragment, which is in the layout.

However, when you change fragments, the original fragment view is detached and removed. When you return to the first fragment, Android creates a new instance of your HomeFragment and its layout. The MainActivity is still referencing the original RecyclerView from the first instance of the HomeFragment, so it will update that view that is no longer on screen and it won't touch the new view. You have actually created a memory leak where the MainActivity is preventing that first fragment's view from being destroyed.

Another issue that you haven't discovered yet possibly is that if you rotate the screen while the SettingsFragment is open, you'll crash with a NullPointerException. This is because a screen rotation will cause a new Activity to be created, so `onCreate()` will be called again, and when it tries to find `recyclerView` when the HomeFragment is not in the layout, it will fail.

It doesn't make sense to work with a Fragment's specific views from the hosting Activity. The Activity should not have to know any details about what is in a Fragment and what to do with the contents of that fragment. All your code that has to do with the RecyclerView should be in HomeFragment.

Comment: Ok so I need to re-configure the code so that the RV elements are inside the HomeFragment.kt instead of MainActivity.kt, Is there a simple way of doing that or would it require me to re-code the entire thing?


Apologies for the simple questions, I'm still new to this and my course instructor isn't very helpful. I still have to remove SQLite functionality and replace it with local XML database storage too.

Comment: I would expect it to be fairly quick to transfer the relevant code via cut/paste. Stuff that was in `onCreate()` of the Activity should be in `onViewCreated()` of the Fragment. And technically, you should use nullable types for any properties that hold references to views in a Fragment and set them back to null in `onDetach`. If you're using ViewBinding, then you only need to do this to a single property, because it internally holds references to all your views.